# Why is pytz wrong by 56 minutes?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I want to convert from a datetime in `America/New_York` to a UTC datetime. As I understand it, `America/New_York` is currently equivalent to `UTC-4`. This means that `Mon Oct 10 12:30:00 2022 (America/New_York)` should convert to `Mon Oct 10 16:30:00 2022 (UTC)`.

Why is pytz reporting `17:26:00` instead?

```py
import pytz
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

utc = timezone('UTC')
nyc = timezone('America/New_York')

dt = datetime(2022, 10, 10, 12, 30, tzinfo = nyc)

print(dt.ctime())

dt_utc = utc.normalize(dt)

print(dt_utc.ctime())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A careful reading of the `pytz` documentation yields this condensed information:

1. This library only supports two ways of building a localized time. The first is to use the `localize()` method provided by the pytz library. This is used to localize a naive datetime (datetime with no timezone information). The second way of building a localized time is by converting an existing localized time using the standard `astimezone()` method.
2. **Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.** It is safe for timezones without daylight saving transitions though, such as UTC. **The preferred way of dealing with times is to always work in UTC, converting to localtime only when generating output to be read by humans.**

This suggests that you should be converting from `UTC` to `America/New_York`, not the other way around, using `astimezone`:

```py
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

utc = timezone('UTC')
nyc = timezone('America/New_York')

dt_utc = datetime(2022, 10, 10, 17, 30, tzinfo=utc)
print(dt_utc)
dt_nyc = dt_utc.astimezone(nyc)
print(dt_nyc)

print('-------------------------')

dt_utc = utc.localize(datetime(2022, 10, 10, 17, 30))
print(dt_utc)
dt_nyc = nyc.localize(datetime(2022, 10, 10, 13, 30))
print(dt_nyc)
print(dt_utc == dt_nyc)
```

Prints:

```None
2022-10-10 17:30:00+00:00
2022-10-10 13:30:00-04:00
-------------------------
2022-10-10 17:30:00+00:00
2022-10-10 13:30:00-04:00
True
```

Comment: What if `datetime(2022, 10, 10, 17, 30)` originates from 'America/New_York', not UTC? I think the point here is that pytz requires you to use `localize` to set a timezone. Yes you can set UTC directly, but that doesn't mean you always have to do that first. Besides, [UTC is no silver bullet either](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/).

Comment: @FObersteiner My point number 1 says that you start with `localize` and once you have a localized `datetime` you *could* convert it to another timezone. Point number 2 says that doing something like `datetime(2022, 10, 10, 17, 30, tzinfo=nyc)` may not work ( even though in my example above it did). I did not mean to imply by showing an example of where I created a UTC `datetime` with `localize` and then used `astimezone` to convert to New York time it was the only way of getting a New York `datetime`, but according to `pytz`'s own documentation, which I quote verbatim, it is the preferred way.